# ¿Cómo centrar dos columnas con HTML, CSS i Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, html5, aplicación-web, responsive, bootstrap-5

Para un trabajo de clase estoy haciendo una página web. De momento todo va bien, pero tengo una duda: ¿cómo puedo tener dos columnas centradas? Es decir, tengo una sección dónde se explican los integrantes del grupo. El caso es que en resoluciones estándar las columnas se muestran correctamente, de forma centrada... sin embargo, en resoluciones 2k o superiores las columnas se ven a bandera derecha. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se vean en el centro de la página, y no a la izquierda?

Gracias

También envío fotos y el código HTML. La primera es cómo se debería ver en resoluciones grandes, la segunda és cómo realmente se ve.

[image: Así es cómo se debería ver en resoluciones grandes]

[image: Así és cómo realmente se ve]

Mi HTML és el siguiente:

```
<div class = "container row justify-content-center", style = "width: 50em 0; margin: 2.25rem;">
            <div class="row justify-content-centejkkkkr">

                <!-- Column 1.x -->
                <div class="col-sm">

                    <!-- Column 1.1 -->
                    <div class="container", style = "width: 50em 0;">
                        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style = "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br/><br/></center>
                        <h2 class="text-center">Manuel Manolo</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi provident autem, facere itaque incidunt voluptatum enim totam eveniet non ratione odit cum nostrum quas minima, illo quasi veritatis fugit maiores?</p>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <!-- Column 1.2 -->
                    <div class="container", style = "width: 50em 0;">
                        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style = "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br/><br/></center>
                        <h2 class = "text-center">Samanta Bucamarit</h2>
                        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius sapiente error labore facere exercitationem voluptatibus laboriosam, ad nam, rerum dignissimos amet voluptates, quos nisi iste fuga accusamus libero? Neque, laborum.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Column 2.x -->
                <div class="col-sm center">

                    <!-- Column 2.1 -->
                    <div class="container cener", style = "width: 50em 0;">
                        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style = "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br/><br/></center>
                        <h2 class="text-center">Pepito de los Palotes</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic fugit nostrum eius perspiciatis tempora temporibus eveniet doloribus itaque delectus, culpa necessitatibus, facilis, voluptates molestias! Placeat quidem optio cum numquam.</p>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <!-- Column 2.2 -->
                    <div class="container", style = "width: 50em 0;">
                        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style = "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br/><br/></center>
                        <h2 class="text-center">Benganito Florencia</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta saepe laboriosam ad molestiae, dignissimos id facere qui tempore sed, ratione et deleniti ipsum velit quisquam reiciendis a minima officia eligendi.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: Hola. Ya viste lo que tienes en el segundo div?             <div class="row justify-content-centejkkkkr">. Y por otro lado, quita el row del primer div

Comment: Tienes varios estilos en linea aplicados a los contenedores, quítalos porque no son útiles y reemplazalos con clases propias de Bootstrap, te estás armando un lío con ese "Width: 50em"

Comment: Gracias bros. Este «justify-content-centejkkkkr»... problemas del editor. Gracias igualmente, ya me funcionó

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He resuelto tu problema, pero te voy a dejar unos puntos a tener en cuenta.

1. Ya que estas usando Bootstrap verifica siempre que las clases que estas usando este bien escritas, tenias un `justify-content-center` en el segundo `row` con caracteres que no coinciden con las especificadas por la documentacion de bootstrap.
2. No es necesario que pongas un `row` dentro de otro `row`, con que tengas uno es suficiente
3. Olvidaate de usar estilos en linea a menos de que sea un HTML para correos, en este caso le aplicaste unos estilos en linea con un ancho fijo a cada elemento, no lo hagas, deja que los elementos se adapten automaticamente al tamaño de la pantalla o en su defecto en este caso con las clases de bootstrap.
4. Como veo que estas usando `twig` ten cuidado con las comas o separadores, no se usan dentro de las etiquetas HTML.
5. Para centrar un `container` en Bootstrap, puedes hacer uso de la clase `.m-auto`

Espero te sirva y Saludos !

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container row justify-content-center m-auto">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <!-- Column 1.x -->
    <div class="col-sm">

      <!-- Column 1.1 -->
      <div class="container">
        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br /><br /></center>
        <h2 class="text-center">Manuel Manolo</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi provident autem, facere itaque incidunt voluptatum enim totam eveniet non ratione odit cum nostrum quas minima, illo quasi veritatis fugit maiores?</p>
      </div>
      <br />

      <!-- Column 1.2 -->
      <div class="container" , style="width: 50em 0;">
        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br /><br /></center>
        <h2 class="text-center">Samanta Bucamarit</h2>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius sapiente error labore facere exercitationem voluptatibus laboriosam, ad nam, rerum dignissimos amet voluptates, quos nisi iste fuga accusamus libero? Neque, laborum.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Column 2.x -->
    <div class="col-sm center">

      <!-- Column 2.1 -->
      <div class="container cener" , style="width: 50em 0;">
        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br /><br /></center>
        <h2 class="text-center">Pepito de los Palotes</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic fugit nostrum eius perspiciatis tempora temporibus eveniet doloribus itaque delectus, culpa necessitatibus, facilis, voluptates molestias! Placeat quidem optio cum numquam.</p>
      </div>
      <br />

      <!-- Column 2.2 -->
      <div class="container" , style="width: 50em 0;">
        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br /><br /></center>
        <h2 class="text-center">Benganito Florencia</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta saepe laboriosam ad molestiae, dignissimos id facere qui tempore sed, ratione et deleniti ipsum velit quisquam reiciendis a minima officia eligendi.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muy útil. Gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Problema resuelto bro, a tu contenedor principal le puse las propiedades margin: auto y display: block

```
<div class = "container row justify-content-center", style = "display: block;margin:auto;width:70%">
            <div class="row justify-content-centejkkkkr">

                <!-- Column 1.x -->
                <div class="col-sm">

                    <!-- Column 1.1 -->
                    <div class="container", style = "width: 50em 0;">
                        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style = "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br/><br/></center>
                        <h2 class="text-center">Manuel Manolo</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi provident autem, facere itaque incidunt voluptatum enim totam eveniet non ratione odit cum nostrum quas minima, illo quasi veritatis fugit maiores?</p>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <!-- Column 1.2 -->
                    <div class="container", style = "width: 50em 0;">
                        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style = "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br/><br/></center>
                        <h2 class = "text-center">Samanta Bucamarit</h2>
                        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius sapiente error labore facere exercitationem voluptatibus laboriosam, ad nam, rerum dignissimos amet voluptates, quos nisi iste fuga accusamus libero? Neque, laborum.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Column 2.x -->
                <div class="col-sm center">

                    <!-- Column 2.1 -->
                    <div class="container cener", style = "width: 50em 0;">
                        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style = "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br/><br/></center>
                        <h2 class="text-center">Pepito de los Palotes</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic fugit nostrum eius perspiciatis tempora temporibus eveniet doloribus itaque delectus, culpa necessitatibus, facilis, voluptates molestias! Placeat quidem optio cum numquam.</p>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <!-- Column 2.2 -->
                    <div class="container", style = "width: 50em 0;">
                        <center><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/integrant.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" style = "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; border-radius: 50%; background-size: 100% auto;"><br/><br/></center>
                        <h2 class="text-center">Benganito Florencia</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta saepe laboriosam ad molestiae, dignissimos id facere qui tempore sed, ratione et deleniti ipsum velit quisquam reiciendis a minima officia eligendi.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Gracias bro !:)